# Counting elements in recursive type alias lists

Tags: recursion, elm

Working from the recursive type alias hints in the [elm-compiler](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.18.0/hints/recursive-alias.md) repository, one solution yields a type signature of:

```
type alias Comment =
  { message : String
  , upvotes : Int
  , downvotes : Int
  , responses : Maybe Responses
  }

type Responses = Responses (List Comment)
```

(where `responses` has been extended to type `Maybe Responses` here to allow an empty response list).

I'm interested in counting the number of elements in such a list, although my current solution seems to be far more complex than needed.

```
count : List Comment -> Int
count comments =
    let
        responses =
            List.concatMap (\c -> flatList c) comments
    in
    List.length responses


flatList : Comment -> List Comment
flatList root =
    let
        rest =
            case root.children of
                Just responseList ->
                    List.concatMap (\child -> flatList child) <| unwrapResponses responseList
                Nothing ->
                    []
    in
    root :: rest

unwrapResponses : Responses -> List Comment
unwrapResponses responses =
    case responses of
        Responses comments ->
            comments
```

Effectively, this unwraps each `Responses` sublist and recursively flattens it. Then, for each of the parent `Comments` we concatenate each of the flat `Responses` lists together and finally get the length of this list.

Since I have no use for this flattened list, I would much prefer to just count each `List.length` as I recurs through the list, then either fold or sum the result (or, use some other method of retrieving the total element count). However, I'm unsure how generate such a solution without returning the `flatList` results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a specialized fold function for comments. Folding is the idea of visiting every element in a structure with a function that accepts the element and some kind of accumulator value so that you can keep some state from step to step.

*Side note: I would recommend you define the Comment `responses` as `Responses` instead of `Maybe Responses` since an empty list and `Nothing` really represent the same thing.*

You could define a `foldl` for a list of Comments like this:

```elm
foldl : (Comment -> b -> b) -> b -> List Comment -> b
foldl f =
    List.foldl
        (\c acc ->
            case c.responses of
                Responses responses ->
                    foldl f (f c acc) responses
        )
```

That means it will first visit the comment node with your function, then all children left to right, accumulating the results along the way.

To use it to determine the length, you simply ignore the comment and increment a counter along the way:

```
length : List Comment
length =
    foldl (\_ acc -> acc + 1) 0
```

You'll see that the [definition of `List.length`](https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/ae5292bd1aac0a04b544b7d361cd902cbd051d72/src/List.elm#L284-L286) uses the same idea of `foldl` for its implementation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanations. Your side note also makes a lot of sense too, so thanks again for the insight.